# How to register multiple queues in NestJs Bull?

Tags: typescript, cron, config, nestjs

I am trying to create multiple queues in NestJs, the documentation says that:

> Create multiple queues by passing multiple comma-separated configuration objects to the registerQueue() method.

But this is not working for me, because when I try to do so, VScode suggests me that I should be mentioning Bull option here, after the comma. Below is my configuration for a single queue, how do I register multiple queues?

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule,
        BullModule.registerQueueAsync({
            name: 'Queue1',
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                redis: {
                    host: configService.get('QUEUE_HOST'),
                    port: +configService.get('QUEUE_PORT'),
                },
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
        HttpModule,
    ],
    controllers: [ScheduleController],
    providers: [MainConsumer], //Service is included here
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 10):

Both the methods registerQueue and registerQueueAsync receive comma separated values as arguments in the met

As NestJS site states:

> Create multiple queues by passing multiple comma-separated configuration objects to the registerQueue() method.

So, basically you have to do the following thing to solve the issue.

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule,
        BullModule.registerQueueAsync({
            name: 'Queue1',
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                redis: {
                    host: configService.get('QUEUE_HOST'),
                    port: +configService.get('QUEUE_PORT'),
                },
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }, {
            name: 'Queue2',
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                redis: {
                    host: configService.get('QUEUE_HOST'),
                    port: +configService.get('QUEUE_PORT'),
                },
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
        HttpModule,
    ],
    controllers: [ScheduleController],
    providers: [MainConsumer], //Service is included here
})

export class AppModule {}
```